# Using localStorage to pass data between different pages

Tags: javascript

I have a shopping basket where i want a user to be able to click on a button that takes them to a separate page whilst capturing their shopping basket contents (item names, quantities, prices, etc). At the moment i'm using localStorage to send just the item names to my new page however the only item that ever prints is the last item to be placed in a basket (i'm not sure how to stop localStorage overwriting data like it does).

This is the itemName section on the basket page.

```
<!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink-->
```

This is a script i have on my basket page.

```
      jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName');


       var arrayShop = [{name: itemName.textContent}];

if(localStorage.getItem("user") == null) { 
 localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify([arrayShop]))
}
else{
  var newArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  newArray.push(arrayShop);
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newArray))
}


});
```

This is the script on a new page

```
 jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

var hst = document.getElementById("add");

console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));

var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));

   for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
 hst.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + items[i].name + "</td><td>"+ items[i].price + 

"</td></tr>";
}





});

 <!--HTML ON THE PAGE -->


    <table id="add">
    <tr><td>Name</td><td>Price</td></tr>
</table>
```

I'm getting the following output which is the last item in the basket (there's 4 items in the basket).

```
Name    
110mm Chair
```

I should be getting.

```
Name
110mm Chair
Red Chair
Green Chair
Grey Chair
```

Below is my shopping cart

```
 <div class="shoppingCartItems">
      <div class="titles2">
        <div class="item-info">[shoppingcart_items]</div>
        <div class="item-qty">[shoppingcart_quantity]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[shoppingcart_price]</div>
        <div class="item-total">[shoppingcart_total]</div>
        <div class="item-remove">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <!--START: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="item-info">
          <div class="product-image"><!--START: itemthumbnail--><a href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]"><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" /></a><!--END: itemthumbnail--><!--START: thumbnailnolink--><img src="thumbnail.asp?file=[THUMBNAIL]" height="55" width="55" id="tnl" /><!--END: thumbnailnolink--></div>
          <div class="product-name-options"> 
            <!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" class ="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink--> 
            <!--START: itemnamenolink--><span id="spnItemName">[ITEM_NAME]</span><!--END: itemnamenolink--> 
            <!--START: itemoptions--> 
            <br />
            <a href='#' onclick="toggle('opt[ITEM_ID]')">View/Hide options</a><br />
            <div id=opt[ITEM_ID] name=opt[ITEM_ID] style="display:none;">[OPTIONS]</div>
            <!--END: itemoptions--> 
            <!--START: recurring_frequency-->
            <div class="recurring_frequency">This item will Autoship every <strong>[recurring_frequency]</strong></div>
            <!--END: recurring_frequency--> 
            <!--START: giftwraplink-->
            <div class="giftwraplink"> <a onclick="showGiftWrap('[ITEM_ID]')">[giftwrap_link]</a> </div>
            <!--END: giftwraplink--></div>
          <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="item-qty">
          <input type="text" name="qtyitemnum" value="[ITEM_QUANTITY]" size="3" maxlength="5" class="txtBoxStyle" />
          <input type="hidden" name="coliditemnum" value="[ITEM_ID]" size="3" maxlength="5" />
          <a href="#" onclick="document.forms['recalculate'].submit();return false;" class="update-qty">[shoppingcart_updatecart]</a>
        </div>
        <div class="item-price" id="itemPrice">[ITEM_PRICE] </div>
        <div class="item-total">[ITEM_SUBTOTAL]</div>
        <div class="item-remove"><a href="#" onclick="document.recalculate.qtyitemnum.value=0;document.recalculate.submit();"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></a></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
      <!--END: SHOPPING_CART_ITEM-->
      <div class="shoppingCartTotal">
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total">[CARTSUBTOTAL]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[shoppingcart_subtotal]</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--START: DISCOUNTS-->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total">[DISCOUNTS]</div>
        <div class="item-price">[checkout1_discounts]</div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <!--END: DISCOUNTS-->
        <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="item-total"><strong>[CARTTOTAL]</strong></div>
        <div class="item-price"><strong>[shoppingcart_total]</strong></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: All your items have the same ID, ID's are supposed to be unique. Give them names or a class and use .getElementsByClass() or .getElementsByName()

Comment: local storage works on the key and value pairs to stop the overwriting you have to give different key to each data

Comment: I've tried changing it to .getElementsByClass('itemName') and that didn't work. How would i give a different key to each data? I'd like it to work on an unlimited amount of items but i'm not sure if that is possible.

Comment: don't try to give all here just make one https://jsfiddle.net and post your code there and give link

Answer (score 0):

I am not getting your shopping cart properly how you are doing it.
but using below code as the reference you can solve your problem.

```
var uname = document.getElementById('uname1').value;

function checkFname(){
    var fname = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;
    var chk_fname = fname.replace(/^[a-zA-z]{2,15}$/, '');
    if (fname != chk_fname) {
        document.getElementById("fname").className = '';
        return true;
    } 
    else if (fname == chk_fname) {
        document.getElementById("fname").className = 'error';
        return false;
    }
}


function Register(){
    var uname = document.getElementById('uname').value;
    var user = {
        'fname':document.getElementById('fname').value,
        };
    localStorage.setItem(uname,JSON.stringify(user));
}
function Validate(){
    Register();
}
```

While inserting the data in local storage `Register()` function will take the `username` as key and `user` can be an array which can contain data.

Comment: Thankyou for the reply really appreciate the help. I've added my shopping cart html code to my OP. I'll give your suggestions a go.

Answer (score 0):

That it is because you are overwriting, not adding. In your code you need to append elements to your storage, using your last record and adding the new one, like this:

```
var arrayShop = {name: 'Chair 2'};
if(localStorage.getItem("user") == null) { 
 localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify([arrayShop]))
}
else{
  var newArray = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  newArray.push(arrayShop);
  localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(newArray))
}
```

In this example my 'Chair 1' is your new element to add, soo if you execute it two times it will add a new element that is what passed in arrayShop.

Comment: Can this work on multiple items with different names? So for example i don't want to hard code any item names into this as i want them to be passed dynamically.

Comment: This will work with any item passed in object, just change your arrayShop to object necessary. like = arrayShop = {name: 'chair 5898'}.
Thats because we are doing an array of objects = [{obj1},{obj2}].
In your case change arrayShop = {name: 'Chair 2'}; to {name: itemName.textContent}

Comment: I'm getting the error newArray.push is not a function

Comment: Let me see how you are aplying it, are you passing an array or an object? array = [{}] obj = {}

Comment: I've updated the code. Just to double check this can definitely be done this way? The fact i'm trying to send local storage items to a completely new page seems rather clunky to me.

Comment: Change your line:  var arrayShop = [{name: itemName.textContent}];
to : var arrayShop = {name: itemName.textContent};